# readr::read_csv() doesn't read dates and returns NA

Tags: r, csv, datetime

I have a csv file `test.csv` with a column containing dates :

```
V1
14-01-02 9:10
14-01-02 9:10
14-01-02 9:21
14-01-02 9:34
14-01-02 9:34
14-01-02 9:34
```

Reading the file with `readr::read_csv` yields `NAs`:

```
V1
1 <NA>
2 <NA>
3 <NA>
4 <NA>
5 <NA>
6 <NA>
Warning message:
9 problems parsing 'test.csv'. See problems(...) for more details.
```

`read.csv` seems to be able to load it like this without a problem but it is too slow. The actual table is 322,509 x 45 and I'd rather not specify each column type with the `col_type`option.

Anyway it could load the column as a character?

Answer (score 6):

You can specify column types in a list where you only name those columns where you do not want readr to try and recognize the column type.

```
read_csv("test.csv", col_types = list(V1 = col_datetime()))
```

See also the [readme on cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/README.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized I can specify which column in the `col_types` option.

Answer (score 1):

From `?read_csv` it says of the `col_type` argument,

> If 'NULL', the column type will be imputed from the first 30
>             rows on the input. This is convenient (and fast), but not
>             robust. If the imputation fails, you'll need to supply the
>             correct types yourself.

It sounds like you might be stuck with

```
read_csv("temp.csv", col_types="T")  # T for datetimes
```

You could also try reading the first line with `read.csv`, getting classes, then reading the whole file with `read_csv`.  You would need to convert character to datetime after the fact.

```
samp <- read.csv("test.csv", nrows=1, strings=F)               # read one row
cols <- sapply(samp, class)                                    # get classes
key <- c("character"="c", "integer"="i", "logical"="l")        # make key, etc.
read_csv("test.csv", col_types=paste(key[cols], collapse=""))  # read with read_csv
```